# UFW - Default Deny Incoming does not block telnet

Tags: firewall, ufw, telnet

I have an Ubuntu `22.04 LTS` Server setup on a VM. I have `ufw` enabled with `default deny incoming` policy

The result of `sudo ufw status verbose` is:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                                
10050/tcp                  ALLOW IN    172.16.103.23             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So, I am assuming that except the specified 2 ports, all other ports cannot be accessed from *outside* network.

Now, on a different machine, I try to **telnet** to the VM server, on the port **80**.
(destination IP has been masked)

```
madhurbhaiya@madhurbhaiya:~$ telnet xxx.xx.xxx.xx 80
Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xx...
Connected to xxx.xx.xxx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The telnet is connected. Why is ufw not blocking ? I have similar observation for port **443**

Another observation is that if I use the same command on a different port, such as **11**, it does not work!

```
madhurbhaiya@madhurbhaiya:~$ telnet xxx.xx.xxx.xx 11
Trying 216.48.190.217...
```

What is causing this differing behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Not try-ed `telnet`.

But I encountered similar problem with `ncat`. Maybe helpful:

When I run `nc -v` with my vps ip and (whatever) port, always printed a `Ncat: Connected to`.
(`nmap` is similar)

That is because I am run-ing a global proxy tool with a tun interface (in detail, `clash` and its `tun mode`) on my local machine ... And probably the proxy hijack the request ...

---

And note that there is [a common issue about `ufw` and *strangely opened port* when using `docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu)